# Ajax concat post array

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code:

```
var data = {};
data.uuid = uuid;
data.method = "addAddress";

//Other parameters
var par = {};
par.name = "test";
par.surname = "test";

data.concat(par); //doesn't work

var url = myURL;
var result = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    async: false
});
```

I want to merge two variables array. It is possible to merge this variables?

Comment: Those are **not** arrays!

Answer (score 0):

Variables `data` and `par` are objects and there is not `concat` method in Objects.. So you end up with a TypeError: "data.concat is not a function".

But you can merge the two Objects like this:

```js
var data = {},
    par = {};

data.uuid = 1234;
data.method = 'addAddress';

par.name = 'test';
par.surname = 'test';

Object.keys(par).forEach(k => data[k] = par[k]);

console.log(data);
```

Note that properties of `data` that are also in `par` will be overwritten.

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
I have changed your var.surname = "test" code into par.surname = "test"

var data = {};
data.uuid = 1;
data.method = "addAddress";

var par = {};
par.name = "test";
par.surname = "test";

var obj = Object.assign({}, data, par);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: excellent solution. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome @facecard